# Proving that $ \tan 2x \cdot (1 + \tan x) \cdot \cot x = \frac{2}{1 - \tan(x)} $

Tags: trigonometry

> Given the following expression,
>   $$ \tan(2x) \cdot (1 + \tan(x)) \cdot \cot(x) $$
>   the exercise asks to simplify the expression and
>   $$ \frac{2}{1 - \tan(x)} $$
>   should be the simplified expression.

I have tried everything I possibly could, including letting WolframAlpha eat it to show alternative forms of the expression – nothing worked.

What do you think? How could I go about simplifying this expression? Thank you.

Comment: How can you re-write $\tan 2x$ in terms of $\tan x$?

Comment: What did you try? It's involves a straightforward simplification

Comment: $\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}$. I know. I have tried.

Comment: @Fehniix: $$\tan(a+b) = \frac{\tan a + \tan b}{1-\tan a \tan b}$$ so $\tan(x+x) = \cdots$?

Comment: @Blue had no clue there was such an equivalence! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining $t := \tan x$ to save typing ...
$$\begin{align}
\tan 2x (1+\tan x) \cot x = \frac{2t}{1-t^2}\cdot(1+t)\cdot\frac{1}{t} = \frac{2t}{(1+t)(1-t)}\cdot(1+t)\cdot\frac{1}{t} = \frac{2}{1-t} 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is true.

Write everything in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, and cancel common factors from numerator and denominator. You should end up with
$$ \frac{2 \cos(x)}{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$$
and then divide numerator and denominator by $\cos(x)$.

Comment: It's actually easier just to write everything in terms of $\tan x$.

Comment: How so, Blue? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan(2x) (1+\tan(x)) \cot(x) = \frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}\left(\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{\cos(x)} \right)\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

Simplifying you get
$$\tan(2x) (1+\tan(x)) \cot(x) = \frac{2(\sin(x)+\cos(x))\cos(x)}{(\cos(x)-\sin(x))(\cos(x)+\sin(x))} = \frac{2\cos(x)}{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$$

i.e.
$$\tan(2x) (1+\tan(x)) \cot(x) =\frac{2}{1-\tan(x)}$$

Comment: Wow. Thank you.